# delete query inner join having

Tags: mysql, having

I made a delete query to delete all records in tbljournaalposten where the field volgr occurs more than once.

```
delete from tbljournaalposten
where tbljournaalposten.ID in(
   SELECT
      tbljournaalposten.ID
   FROM
      invoerdatum 
   INNER JOIN
      rabobank2_2 ON rabobank2_2.IBAN_BBAN = invoerdatum.IBAN_BBAN 
   INNER JOIN
      tbljournaalposten ON rabobank2_2.Volgnr = tbljournaalposten.Volgnr
   WHERE
      rabobank2_2.invoerdatum = invoerdatum.invoerdatum
   GROUP BY  tbljournaalposten.volgnr
   HAVING  tbljournaalposten.volgnr >1

   ORDER BY
      rabobank2_2.Datum DESC )
```

When I try the code in phpmyadmin nothing seems to happen. It is loading for a long time. But after 5 minutes the query stops. When I look in the table thet recors with volgnr > 1 are deleted.
When I only try this code it works good and direct.

```
SELECT
  tbljournaalposten.ID
FROM
  invoerdatum 
INNER JOIN
  rabobank2_2 ON rabobank2_2.IBAN_BBAN = invoerdatum.IBAN_BBAN 
INNER JOIN
  tbljournaalposten ON rabobank2_2.Volgnr = tbljournaalposten.Volgnr
WHERE
  rabobank2_2.invoerdatum = invoerdatum.invoerdatum
GROUP BY   tbljournaalposten.volgnr
HAVING  tbljournaalposten.volgnr >1

ORDER BY
  rabobank2_2.Datum DESC
```

I tried sereral times. I expected that the recores with volgr >1 are deleted.

Comment: How many records are returned from the sub query ?  when that number is high you might do a `WHERE NOT IN( select records you want to keep )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code and now it works. Thanks for the help.

```
delete from tbljournaalposten
where tbljournaalposten.ID in(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
  tbljournaalposten.ID
FROM
  invoerdatum 
INNER JOIN
  rabobank2_2 ON rabobank2_2.IBAN_BBAN = invoerdatum.IBAN_BBAN 
INNER JOIN
  tbljournaalposten ON rabobank2_2.Volgnr = tbljournaalposten.Volgnr
WHERE
  rabobank2_2.invoerdatum = invoerdatum.invoerdatum
GROUP BY  tbljournaalposten.volgnr
HAVING  count(DISTINCT tbljournaalposten.ID) > 1
) sub
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query may delete that rows, which you dont want, so just make sure to not lose data in `tbljournaalposten`, (create copy of table or something like).

I guess you need something like:

```
delete from tbljournaalposten
where tbljournaalposten.volgnr in(
    SELECT volgnr FROM (
        SELECT
          tbljournaalposten.volgnr
        FROM
          invoerdatum 
        INNER JOIN
          rabobank2_2 ON rabobank2_2.IBAN_BBAN = invoerdatum.IBAN_BBAN 
        INNER JOIN
          tbljournaalposten ON rabobank2_2.Volgnr = tbljournaalposten.Volgnr
        WHERE
          rabobank2_2.invoerdatum = invoerdatum.invoerdatum
        GROUP BY  tbljournaalposten.volgnr
        HAVING  count(DISTINCT tbljournaalposten.ID) > 1
    ) sub
);
```

Also `ORDER BY` in sub query does not make sense in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the code but it doesn't work. I also have the same problem. When I only try the sub query it gives me 2 records.

Comment: This query should throw and error You can't specify target table 'tbljournaalposten' for update in FROM clause..dropping the select down a level should help ie in(
    select * from (SELECT
      tbljournaalposten.volgnr ...) s

Comment: @Johan - Did you get error which  P.Salmon mentioned? Just updated answer, so check please if that works now? and if not ,what do you getting? some error? or just not removing expected rows ?

Comment: @P.Salmon - Thanks for mentionig that, I did not tested query, just updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code but now all records with Volgnr> 1 are deleted.

```
delete from tbljournaalposten
where tbljournaalposten.volgnr in(
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      tbljournaalposten.volgnr
    FROM
      invoerdatum 
    INNER JOIN
      rabobank2_2 ON rabobank2_2.IBAN_BBAN = invoerdatum.IBAN_BBAN 
    INNER JOIN
      tbljournaalposten ON rabobank2_2.Volgnr = tbljournaalposten.Volgnr
    WHERE
      rabobank2_2.invoerdatum = invoerdatum.invoerdatum
    GROUP BY  tbljournaalposten.volgnr
    HAVING  count(DISTINCT tbljournaalposten.ID) > 1
) sub
 );
```